# How to preserve the fixed sequence of keys in Hashtable?

Tags: java, hashtable

This code create a Hashtable as follows:

```
"00:00-01:00" - 0, "01:00-02:00" - 0, ..., "23:00-00:00" - 0

Hashtable<String,Integer> distr = new Hashtable<String,Integer>();
numHoursPerDay = 24;
int interval;
int[] count = new int[numHoursPerDay];
String[] intervals = new String[numHoursPerDay];

for (int h = 0 ; h != 24 ; h++) {
    intervals[h] = String.format("%02d:00-%02d:00", h, ((h+1)%24));
    distr.put(intervals[h], count[h]);
}
```

However, the sequence of keys in `distr` is random, e.g.

```
"10:00-11:00" - 0, "23:00-00:00" - 0, "00:00-01:00" - 0, ...
```

How can I preserve the sequence given in `intervals` when saving keys in `distr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `LinkedHashMap` instead, you will be able to iterate it in insertion order. It's also possible to use a `LinkedHashMap` in a last-used configuration.